# Linux Network namespaces unexpected behavior

Tags: go, linux-kernel, kernel, ubuntu-14.04, linux-namespaces

So I've been playing around with Network namespaces recently.
I put together a simple code, built it and noticed something very weird happening.

The code is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "path"
    "syscall"
)

const (
    NsRunDir  = "/var/run/netns"
    SelfNetNs = "/proc/self/ns/net"
)

func main() {
    netNsPath := path.Join(NsRunDir, "myns")
    os.Mkdir(NsRunDir, 0755)

    if err := syscall.Mount(NsRunDir, NsRunDir, "none", syscall.MS_BIND, ""); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not create Network namespace: %s", err)
    }

    fd, err := syscall.Open(netNsPath, syscall.O_RDONLY|syscall.O_CREAT|syscall.O_EXCL, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not create Network namespace: %s", err)
    }
    syscall.Close(fd)

    if err := syscall.Unshare(syscall.CLONE_NEWNET); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not clone new Network namespace: %s", err)
    }

    if err := syscall.Mount(SelfNetNs, netNsPath, "none", syscall.MS_BIND, ""); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not Mount Network namespace: %s", err)
    }

    if err := syscall.Unmount(netNsPath, syscall.MNT_DETACH); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not Unmount new Network namespace: %s", err)
    }

    if err := syscall.Unlink(netNsPath); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not Unlink new Network namespace: %s", err)
    }

    ifcs, _ := net.Interfaces()
    for _, ifc := range ifcs {
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", ifc)
    }
}
```

Now, when you run this code on Trusty 14.04, you will see something weird happening.
This happens when you run the binary **several times in a row**.

Sometimes it prints out all Host's interfaces, sometimes it simply prints out just a loopback interface which means that the range loop at the end of the program seems to be executing once when the namespace is still attached and sometimes when it's already been detached.

I'm totally confused why this is happening but I'm thinking it's either my code or maybe I'm just missing out something in terms of the program execution or some kernel stuff.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks

**Update1:**
So it seems the "strange" behaviour has to do with how golang schedules goroutines across OS Threads. So you need to make sure that you handle the runtime well. What I mean by that is, that if you lock the code execution to one OS Thread you will get consistent results. You can do this by adding the following runtime package statement:

```
runtime.LockOSThread()
```

However this still does not solve my problem, but now I think it all comes down to understanding of Namespaces. I need to look more into that.

**Update2:**
To give you a little bit more context into why you should use the above OS Thread Lock when running bunch of syscalls and experience the similar "strangeness" of correct behavior, give ththis [blogpost](http://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler) a read. It describes runtime and go schedulers. It was written for go 1.1 but it still gives very good overview.

Comment: I've got nothing but see if this still happens with tip.

Comment: On `go v1.3rc2` (tip from today), it only prints `lo`, ran it about 20 times to be sure, running kernel 3.15 on arch linux.